# Neo4j bidirectional traversal api

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

I am playing around with Neo4j and so far I have a geographical graph where an `AIRPORT` is connect to a `CITY`, the `CITY` to a `COUNTRY` and the `COUNTRY` to a `CONTINENT`, as depicted in the picture[image]

Labels on the arrows translate to `org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType` into my code. So far, I can build the path between the start node `MXP` to the end node `LTN` using the following mono-directional traversal.

```
Traverser traverse = database.traversalDescription().depthFirst()
  .relationships(CITY, BOTH)
  .relationships(CONTINENT, BOTH)
  .relationships(COUNTRY, BOTH)
  .relationships(REGION, BOTH)
  .evaluator(Evaluators.includeWhereEndNodeIs(endNode)).traverse(startNode);
```

With this, I get a single path `MXP -> Milan -> Italy -> Europe <- England <- London <- LTN`, which is correct given the graph description, the traversal description and of course my understanding my understanding of such description.

I am trying to change this code to perform a bidirectional traversal, meaning I want to start from both `MXP` and `LTN` and stop at the collision point. I tried with the following snippet, where comments mean my understanding so it may easier to point out the problem.

```
TraversalDescription startSide = database.traversalDescription().depthFirst() //Depth first algorithm
  .relationships(CITY, OUTGOING) //consider CITY relationship, only outgoing
  .relationships(REGION, OUTGOING) //consider REGION relationship, only outgoing
  .relationships(COUNTRY, OUTGOING) //consider COUNTRY relationship, only outgoing
  .relationships(CONTINENT, OUTGOING) //consider CONTINENT relationship, only outgoing
  .evaluator(Evaluators.excludeStartPosition()); //do not consider the starting point. 
                                               //Here I tried also with all, with the same result
                                               //with includeWhereEndNodeIs(endNode), again with same result
                                               //and combining includeWhereEndNodeIs and excludeStartPosition, once more with same result.
                                               //All tries I mirrored for the endSide description, changing endNode to startNode where I feel it was needed

TraversalDescription endSide = database.traversalDescription().depthFirst()
  .relationships(CITY, OUTGOING)
  .relationships(REGION, OUTGOING)
  .relationships(COUNTRY, OUTGOING)
  .relationships(CONTINENT, OUTGOING)
  .evaluator(Evaluators.excludeStartPosition());

List<Node> asList = Arrays.asList(startNode, endNode);
Traverser traverse = database.bidirectionalTraversalDescription().endSide(endSide).startSide(startSide).traverse(asList, asList);
```

Here, instead of the path I am getting with the monodirectional traversal try, I get two paths, one with only `MXP` and one with only `LTN`.

At this point I seriously believe I am completely misunderstanding the bidirectional traversal and maybe even its purpose. Where is my mistake? Why I do not get the same output?

Comment: maybe studying through the tests https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/kernel/src/test/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/traversal/TestBidirectionalTraversal.java helps to get more understanding.

Comment: I already found them, but did not take time to read them thoroughly. Now I spent some this 50 minutes to read them and are well written and understandable. I still haven't solved my problem, but I guess I will be able to after going even deeper. Thank you @StefanArmbruster!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a working solution. The problem in my code was related to the concept of [uniqueness](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html#_uniqueness). Interesting points for my problem are

> Sets the rules for how positions can be revisited during a traversal as stated in Uniqueness. Default if not set is NODE_GLOBAL.
>
> NODE_GLOBAL uniqueness: No node in the entire graph may be visited more than once. This could potentially consume a lot of memory since it requires keeping an in-memory data structure remembering all the visited nodes.
>
> NODE_PATH uniqueness: A node may not occur previously in the path reaching up to it.

These descriptions are somehow different from the [official API](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/Uniqueness.html) so I played around trying different combination and ended up with the following code:

```
TraversalDescription bothSide = database.traversalDescription().depthFirst()
    .relationships(CITY, OUTGOING)
    .relationships(REGION, OUTGOING)
    .relationships(COUNTRY, OUTGOING)
    .relationships(CONTINENT, OUTGOING)
    .uniqueness(NODE_PATH);
  
Traverser traverser = database
    .bidirectionalTraversalDescription()
    .startSide(bothSide)
    .endSide(bothSide)
    .traverse(node, endNode);
```

Basically, I defined a common `TraversalDescription` for both the end and the start side, where I want to follow only [OUTGOING](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/Direction.html#OUTGOING) relationships and I want to consider paths only where nodes are unique inside the path itself.

Then, I defined a `bidirectional traverser` which simply sets up the end and the start side and traverses the graph from the starting node `node` to the end node `endNode` (well, actually it traverses from start to end AND from end to start at the same time and stops when the two traversal collide, merging the resulting paths into a single path leading from `start` to `end`).

**NOTE**: I am not completely sure about the meaning of `NODE_GLOBAL`, since in my database each node represents a geographic entity, so each node in the path `MXP -> Milan -> Italy -> Europe <- England <- London <- LTN` should be visited only once and thus there should be no difference between `NODE_GLOBAL` and `NODE_PATH` in this context.